# How to rename a django model in an application by changing letter case

Tags: python, django

I have a django model in my app that looks like this(assuming all required modules are imported)

```
class profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    mobile_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="phone number must be entered in hte format '+23474857934'. Up to 15 digits allowed")
    mobile = models.CharField(validators=[mobile_regex], max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
```

I made a (silly)mistake spelling the profile name(using a lowercase to start the model name instead of uppercase), and would like to correct this, is there a way to this without affecting the data that might already be stored.

changing the name from **profile** to **Profile** and making a migration doesn't reflect the change, and I don't get the usual..
"Did you rename  `appname.oldModelName` to `appname.NewModelName`? [y/N]" query

I'm sorry if this question seems a bit trivial,I'm a newbie at django thanks for understanding

Comment: Where exactly are you mistaken and what commands have you tried till now?

Comment: change the name of model, run make migration command and then run migrate, make sure you change the name of model where ever you have made imports.

Comment: @SuhasJahad yes I have tried to do that, but I see now that I did not indicate that I meant that I just wanted to change the name from __profile__ to __Profile__ and this does not trigger the rename query when I try to make a migration, thanks

Comment: @maroofshittu basically what Django does is that it creates a table for your model like this: `applabel_modelname` and all lowercase unless you specify the name of the table. So changing One letter to uppercase does not reflect on DB table name.

Comment: @ruddra ok thanks, but I realized this means I would have to make all my queries referring to the model in whatever way I named it(uppercase or lower) I'd hoped I could change it to feel more conventional, or in case of a future case when I'm required to do so by a supervisor

Comment: @maroofshittu You can query like: `Profile.objects.all()` and it should return all entries in the existing table.

Comment: do you have access to create the table?

Comment: @noobEditor yes I have access

Comment: @maroofshittu, when you change the name, Django migrations is going to ask you if you want to rename the model and if you choose "yes" it will  rename the table with `ALTER TABLE "old_name" RENAME TO "new_name"`. It won't drop the table. If you choose "no", table will be dropped and a new table created.

Comment: @Borut Thanks, this has already been suggested, I'm aware that renaming a model before making a migration results in the question of if you want to rename the model or not , but it doesn't ask this question if I only changed the case of one or more letters.(from uppercase to lowercase)

Comment: @maroofshittu, I must have mixed up the questions, I guess. I was pretty sure there was something about dropping the table in the question.

Comment: yes I'm sorry about that,  I realize now that might have been a bit misleading

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to work around this

Django does not recognize a rename if you only change the letter case so, these steps helped me solved the problem:

1. change the name of the model completely(Something simple like 'temp'), and run the `makemigrations` command (this will be recognized and django will ask you if you want to rename- enter 'y')
2. then change it back this time using the proper casing for the letters
3. then run the `makemigrations` command again. and rename.

This only affects the model name and not the table name in your actual database(these are usually named in all lowercase by default)